# Comment and for loop is not working in Azure function "main" method

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am new to python and Azure function and facing a strange issue. When I comment or write a "for" loop outside of Azure function's "main" method, it looks to be working and color also gets changed.
But inside "main" function its not working. Here is the sample:

Please see the image attached.
In line number 10 and 11, the comment and for loop looks to be working and text colors are also changed.
In line number 17 and 20, the comment is not working and color is also not changed. Second for loop is added just to show color is not changing.
Any help will be great full. I am using VS Code and calling this Azure function via logic app.

```
#global shiftDate
for x in y:
    
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    shiftDate = date.today()
    shiftDate = str(shiftDate.day) + '-' + str(shiftDate.strftime('%b')) + '-' + str

(shiftDate.strftime('%y'))
    #headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    reqbody = req.get_body()
    samplelist = ['Fruits','Vegetables','Milk']
    for item in samplelis:
            
                
    return func.HttpResponse(body = str(reqbody))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you pls help me with the VS Code version you are making use of ?

Comment: Hi Sathya ....I am using 1.47.3 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by checking the sample python code for Azure functions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-06

Even in the sample function the color was not changed and it was working fine. Not sure why.
I modified my code and got the expected results. Note : Still the color for "for" loop and comments not working in the "main" function.